# How to choose Clebsch-Gordan coefficients?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, group-theory, representation-theory

I just started learning [Clebsch-Gordan coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients) recently. I want to use the expression on Wikipedia (relation to Wigner $3j$ symbols):

$$
\langle j_{1},m_{1},j_{2},m_{2}|J,M\rangle=(-1)^{-j_{1}+j_{2}-M}
\begin{pmatrix}                
  j_{1} & j_{2} & J \\
  m_{1} & m_{2} & -M \\
\end{pmatrix}\\
$$
For $M = 5$, because $M ∈ \{-J, -J+1, ..., J\}$, then I choose $J = 5, 6$ and calculate
$$
\bigg\langle\frac{7}{2},\frac{7}{2},\frac{5}{2},\frac{3}{2}\bigg|5,5\bigg\rangle=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{7}{3}}}{2}\\
\bigg\langle\frac{7}{2},\frac{7}{2},\frac{5}{2},\frac{3}{2}\bigg|6,5\bigg\rangle =\frac{\sqrt{\frac{5}{3}}}{2}
$$
So I think I could get below relation.
$$
\bigg|\frac{7}{2},\frac{7}{2},\frac{5}{2},\frac{3}{2}\bigg\rangle=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{7}{3}}}{2}|5,5\rangle\\
\bigg|\frac{7}{2},\frac{7}{2},\frac{5}{2},\frac{3}{2}\bigg\rangle=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{5}{3}}}{2}|6,5\rangle
$$
I wonder why there are two expressions. Which one should I choose? I also try other values of $j_1$, $j_2$, $m_1$, $m_2$, if the $(-1)$ term exists, some results become negative, should I consider?

Comment: Think a bit more about the equations you write after "So I think I could get below relation"... Try simpler examples, suppose |psi> is a combination of |a>, |b> and |c>. Does <psi|a>=2 imply that |psi>=2|a>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in going from $\langle \ell_1 m_1;\ell_2 m_2\vert JM\rangle = a $ to
$\vert \ell_1 m_1;\ell_2 m_2\rangle = a \vert J M\rangle$.  The Clebsch-Gordan coefficients are change-of-basis coefficients from the uncoupled basis
$\{\vert \ell_1 m_1,\ell_2 m_2\rangle\}$ to the coupled basis $\{\vert JM\rangle\}$.  States in the coupled basis are rarely equal to states in the uncoupled basis; in general they will be linear combinations (*i.e.* sums) of states in the uncoupled basis.

As an analogy, consider a first set of basis vector in the plane
$\{\hat x,\hat y\}$ and decompose those in a second set $\{\hat X,\hat Y\}$ where this last is rotated by $\pi/4$ w/r to the first set.  Then surely
\begin{align}
\hat x= \hat X \langle X\vert x\rangle + \hat Y \langle Y\vert x\rangle 
\end{align}
where $\langle A\vert b\rangle = \vec A\cdot \vec b$.  Here, we have
\begin{align}
\langle X\vert x\rangle = \langle Y\vert x\rangle =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\, ,
\tag{1}
\end{align}
since both sets differ by a $\pi/4$ rotation. These overlaps are change-of-basis coefficients, *i.e.* they play in this example the role of the CG in your original question.

Of course, Eq.(1) does NOT imply
\begin{align}
\hat X=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\hat x\, ,\quad \hat Y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\hat x\, ,
\quad
\hat x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\hat X\, ,\quad 
\hat x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\hat Y\, ,
\end{align}
but it does imply that the sum
\begin{align}
\hat x= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\hat X +\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\hat Y
\end{align}
is an equality.

In your specific case one has (for instance)
\begin{align}
\big\langle\textstyle{\frac{7}{2}},\frac{7}{2};\frac{5}{2},\frac{3}{2}\big|\,5,5\big\rangle=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{7}{3}}}{2}\, ,\qquad 
\big\langle\textstyle{\frac{7}{2}},\frac{5}{2},\frac{5}{2};\frac{5}{2}\big|\, 5,5\big\rangle =-\frac{\sqrt{\frac{5}{3}}}{2}
\end{align}
so that
\begin{align}
\vert 5,5\rangle = \textstyle\frac{\sqrt{\frac{7}{3}}}{2}\vert \frac{7}{2},
\frac{7}{2};\frac{5}{2},\frac{3}{2}\rangle
-\frac{\sqrt{\frac{5}{3}}}{2}
\vert \frac{7}{2},
\frac{5}{2};\frac{5}{2},\frac{5}{2}\rangle\, .
\end{align}